# How to use ubsan with libFuzzer (on clang)?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I am currently getting started with fuzzing in C++.  Following the tutorial at https://github.com/google/fuzzer-test-suite/blob/master/tutorial/libFuzzerTutorial.md I have successfully used the AddressSanitizer.  In that tutorial it is also recommended to at least try UBSan as well.

The example from the [documentation on UBSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) work just fine, I immediatly get a runtime error because of the signed integer overflow.  But when I try to build a fuzzer around the example I no longer get any errors reported.

The example code is

```
// test.cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int k = 0x7fffffff;
    k += argc;
    return 0;
}
```

which I compiled with `clang++ -fsanitize=undefined test.cpp -o test`.

To get my fuzzer I changed the code to

```
// fuzz.cpp
#include <cstddef>

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const char *data, size_t len)
{
    int k = 0x7fffffff;
    k += len;
    return 0;
}
```

and built it with `clang++ -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined -fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard fuzz.cpp libFuzzer.a -o fuzz`.

Does any one know what I have to change, so that the fuzzer also finds the signed integer overflow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the difference between your two examples is the use of `size_t` in the second one for `len`, which changes the add in `+=` to being done with unsigned arithmetic. Overflow is defined for unsigned so the sanitizer doesn't flag it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @zalman-stern, this was indeed the problem.  Even though unsigned overflow is defined UBSan has a sanitizer to also catch it.  Sadly, even if you enable this, it still does not catch the overflow.